# Fatal Exception null object reference in Android studio

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

I'm working on an app where on a button click, the app will take the user from main activity to new activity. I've got everything coded and I am just trying to link up the activities now but I'm getting fatal errors which I cannot really understand. The app crashes when I try the button in testing and in Debug I get the error which I have pasted below. I've also pasted my code for the button and the XML for main activity. Can anybody help me make some sense of this error please? Also, if I have left any information out please let me know. Thanks.

Note: In the code for my button, the button I get the error with is the newactivity one.

**Error:**

```
2021-06-15 21:15:39.489 8340-8340/com.project.playshow E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.project.playshow, PID: 8340
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.project.playshow/com.fproject.playshow.newactivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3449)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3601)
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
    at com.project.playshow.newctivity.onCreate(newactivity.kt:97)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8000)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7984)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1309)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3422)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3601) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
```

**Code used in MainActivity for Button** (newactivityopen is the one I'm having issues with)

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        var dialogbutton = findViewById<Button>(R.id.dialogbtn)
        dialogbutton.setOnClickListener{
            openDialogue()
        }
        
        var newactivityopen = findViewById<Button>(R.id.button_newactivity)
        newactivityopen.setOnClickListener{
            var intent = Intent(this, newactivity::class.java)
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }
```

**XML File**

```
       <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/dialogbtn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/app_name"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_newactivity"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="569dp"
        android:text="NewActivity"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: You use this odd pattern twice. `var something = findViewById...` `somethingElse.setOnClickListener...` In both cases, why would `somethingElse` be anything but null when you haven't set what they are yet? Can you show the part of your Activity class where you define the properties?

Comment: I think there's still some error in the code you have up. I don't find `button_newactivity` initialised anywhere. Please correct it.

Comment: Isn't it initialised here?   var newactivityopen = findViewById<Button>(R.id.button_newactivity)
        button_newactivity.setOnClickListener{

Comment: @CloakedArrow then it should be `newactivityopen.setOnClickListener`

Comment: Ah yep sorry, let me copy and paste the entire code from my backup file, I seem to have made some errors restoring code while I was trying trial and error method of fixing this issue.....in hindsight this is probably what I should've done before.

Answer (score 1):

I´m not familiar with Kotlin (only java), but is it possible that you have setted the `onClickListener` to a `Button`, which doesn´t exist?

Try replacing these code snippets:

`sdkButton.setOnClickListener`  with  `dialogbutton.setOnClickListener`

`button_newactivity.setOnClickListener` with `newactivityopen.setOnClickListener`

Comment: Thanks Dorian for fixing my question and giving me your answer. No sorry that's my fault. That part is for the top button which works, the only reason it's different in my provided code is because I changed it when I was trying to fix the issue myself and forgot to change it back before posting it on here. I'll fix the code now.